# Unit Testing - do edge cases require separate test methods?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

When unit testing, should edge cases testing the same method each require a separate test method.  For example, testing for an empty string passed to the following function:

```
public function add($numbers)
{
    $numbers = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $numbers);
    if ($numbers === "") {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

i obviously want to catch edge cases such as:

```
""
" " 
"\t \n"
"asd"
```

etc

So how many test methods would be required to prove this method works?

```
public function testAddEmptyString()
{
    $stringCalculator = new StringCalculator();
    $this->assertSame(0, $stringCalculator->add(""));
}

public function testAddEmptyStringWithSpaces()
{
    $stringCalculator = new StringCalculator();
    $this->assertSame(0, $stringCalculator->add("  "));
}

public function testAddEmptyStringWithCharacters()
{
    $stringCalculator = new StringCalculator();
    $this->assertSame(0, $stringCalculator->add("asd"));
}
```

This seems like the test class would contain massive amounts of methods for anything non trivial

Answer (score 1):

In this simple case (an actual function, i.e. no side effects, no exceptions and basically one line per test case) I'd say that a single test method would be fine.

If you have more complex test cases that require setup code, then each should get its own test method.

Answer (score 0):

This is ofcourse a matter of opinion, so IMHO, a test method should test a single scenario, *always*.

Having said that, and taking into account that you should treat your test code with the same loving attention as production code, you should strive for a clean design - In this case, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Every language has its own ways of achieving this, but usually extracting a method will do the trick. In itself, There is no harm in having many tests, provided that they are isolated, clear in intention, etc..

As an example, the way in which xUnit (C#) solved this issue is shown in the following pattern:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("")]
[InlineData(" ")]
[InlineData("\t \n")]
[InlineData("asd")]
public void Add_NonNumber_ZeroReturned(string numbers)
{
    var underTest = new UnderTest();
    var result = underTest.Add(numbers);
    Assert.Equal(0, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have lots of separate test methods, don't be concerned about how many of them there are.

The bad thing about trying to shoehorn multiple tests into a method is that when the tests fail you don't know the true extent of the breakage, because a failure of one part of the test prevents the rest of the test from running. 
When you see a test break and go fix it, the result may be more failures popping up.

If you organize your tests so that the different cases are handled in separate tests then you will see all the failures at once.

If all the edge cases are instances of passing in different data and they all get called the same way you might want to check into whether your test framework supports parameterized tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an array of all of these edge case values separate from your test.

```
String[] edgeCaseValues = {""," ","\t \n","asd"};
```

then in a test you can simply loop through them passing them into your function

```
foreach(var edgeCaseValue in edgeCaseValues)
{
    $stringCalculator = new StringCalculator();
    $this->assertSame(0, $stringCalculator->add(edgeCaseValue));
}
```

This way you can then reuse them in other tests and if you add a new edge case value they will all get added to all tests